# Disallow Facebook friends who have marked me as "close" from viewing posts they are not allowed to see

Tags: facebook, email, privacy, account-management

Step 1: I update my status with an image on Facebook, and I set the "visibility" to be custom, and exclude a person from seeing it.

Step 2: That person has me marked as a "close friend", and receives a "close friend notification" via email that contains the entire contents of my post, including the picture.

Step 3: When that person clicks the link in the email, they get the standard "content unavailable message" in their browser because they are not allowed to see the post.

Why is that person getting an email notification for my post after I have specifically said they should not be able to see the post? How can I disallow friends such as this from receiving notifications for post they are not allowed to access?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue that should be reported to Facebook as a bug.  They probably didn't consider this type of situation when they programmed the notifications for Close Friends.

Here's the link to report the bug:

https://www.facebook.com/help/326603310765065/